# How to solve problems with launching? (Win 7, 64 Bit)

Tags: anno-1503

I recently dug up Anno 1503 again - German version, Königsedition.

Well, it doesn't work (Win 7). I spent last evening looking for solutions to the problem, i.e. installing as Admin, installing in a different location, compatibility mode - no luck. On launching the executable there's some seconds of loading (as indicated by the mouse-arrow) and then nothing.

Now, there does seem to be an inofficial patch 1.01 for that version which will likely solve the problem - however I don't know whether it is appropriate to ask for something like that here.

So, my question is whether someone does have another idea by which I could make the game work after all, maybe without said patch - well, more or less I'm asking for advice due to myself being having grown sort of desperate.

Thanks for everyone's time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've decided to just spend the few euros and get the Gold edition which works with Windows 7, then. Nothing seems to work, after all, and that 1.01 patch seems to be lost in the annals of the internet.

Thanks to everyone trying to help.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I don't have enough rep to comment, but I found a solution that may help you from the site: www.gamersgate.com/gametutor?issue=237765.

> "...after some testing we have found out that windows 7 has a few problems with the >scenes.cach and inselcache.txt (random generator)! these are two files at a neuinstalation >not exist and therefore there are no . Problem in our fall, taking over the old >installation, from eg xp, they must be two files are deleted. they are located here: C: \ >Program Files (x86) \ Anno 1503 \ Scenes C: \ Program Files (x86) \ Anno 1503 \ Scenes \ >Islands which were the original paths. now should go play again."

Sorry, it was translated from German and I couldn't find the original phrase to provide for you. Let me know if this helped at all.

Comment: Sorry, that yielded no results. Thanks for the effort.

Answer (score 0):

I know you have run in compatability mode but make sure it is setup up exactly like this.

Compatibility with XP sp3 - and also tick run as administrator

If this still doesn't work please could you check that you have directx completely upto date and also your video drivers.

If this still doesn't work, try reinstalling it and using this method again before actually running the game, this is how i fixed the same issue a few months ago with windows 8

Comment: DX up-to-date: Check /

Video Drivers up-to-date: Check /

SP3/Admin: Tried before and after reinstall (as Admin). /

Yet, the problem persists!

- 
Thanks for the input, though.

Answer (score 0):

I have a Possible reasonable fix to run Anno 1503 on windows 10. Go to Regedit (look online if you need help), then double click on these folders as you find them
HKEY_CURRENT_USER, SOFTWARE, MICROSOFT, Windows NT, CurrentVersion, AppCompatFlags, then layers. Now look for Anno 1503 entry (hope you have one there cuz I don't know how to help there), now in the Data section for Anno 1503 put this case sensitive info DWM8And16BitMitigation HIGHDPIAWARE WIN98 RUNASADMIN now run game in lowest display resolution 800x600?, the game will run at about 15-20FPS